# Net Present Value of multiple arrays along an axis

Tags: python

I have an array x  of size (100L,31L). I want to get the net present value of each array on axis 1 (so each cash flow series would the 31L) and turn it into an array y (100L).

Comment: Can you give us more data to be able to help you?

Comment: So for example if I have  x = [[1,6,5,4],[1,6,9,8],[6,5,1,4]] and I want to create an array that returns the net present value (using the numpy function np.npv) of each of those lists. I would have a resulting array giving me the net present value y = [n1,n2,n3].

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something as simple as this?

```
import numpy as np

x = [[1,6,5,4],[1,6,9,8],[6,5,1,4]]
rate = 0.2     
out = [np.npv(rate, i) for i in ars]
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but just in case it helps...

You can use `np.apply_along_axis` for this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy_financial import npv  # as np.npv is deprecated now

rate = 0.2

data = np.array([[1, 6, 5, 4], [1, 6, 9, 8], [6, 5, 1, 4]])

np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: npv(rate, x), 1, data)
```

and you get

```
array([11.78703704, 16.87962963, 13.17592593])
```

If you wanted to work out the NPV for each column:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: npv(rate, x), 0, data)
```

and you get

```
array([ 6.        , 14.47222222, 13.19444444, 13.44444444])
```